# IP Address from host name

Tags: iphone

i need to get the ip address from the given host name. For example,if "google.com" is given i need the ip address of google.com. How to achive this in iphone?

Answer (score 4):

For iPhone, use [CFHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFHostRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

See the POSIX function [`getaddrinfo()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like any other POSIX systems, i.e. use `getaddrinfo()` (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo).